# Can UPS Address Validation API be used in webshop?

Tags: street-address, ups, ups-api

Imagine a standard webshop with a standard checkout flow where the customer must enter a valid shipping address.
I'm looking for a good usage of the **UPS Address Validation - Street Level API** but can't seem to grasp how to use the suggestion in a meaningful way.

### Scenario

Customers correct address is

> 2060 N KENTUCKY ST
>   ARLINGTON VA 22205
>   USA

**Case: Customer enters incorrect house number**

Instead of *2060* he enters *2600*

**Suggestions from API**

```
"Candidate": [{
        "AddressKeyFormat": {
            "AddressLine": "2600 S KENT ST",
            "PoliticalDivision2": "ARLINGTON",
            "PoliticalDivision1": "VA",
            "PostcodePrimaryLow": "22202",
            "PostcodeExtendedLow": "2218",
            "Region": "ARLINGTON VA 22202-2218",
            "CountryCode": "US"
        }
    }, {
        "AddressKeyFormat": {
            "AddressLine": "1000-1098 N KENTUCKY ST",
            "PoliticalDivision2": "ARLINGTON",
            "PoliticalDivision1": "VA",
            "PostcodePrimaryLow": "22205",
            "PostcodeExtendedLow": "2310",
            "Region": "ARLINGTON VA 22205-2310",
            "CountryCode": "US"
        }
    }, {
        "AddressKeyFormat": {
            "AddressLine": "1001-1099 N KENTUCKY ST",
            "PoliticalDivision2": "ARLINGTON",
            "PoliticalDivision1": "VA",
            "PostcodePrimaryLow": "22205",
            "PostcodeExtendedLow": "2309",
            "Region": "ARLINGTON VA 22205-2309",
            "CountryCode": "US"
        }
    }, {
        "AddressKeyFormat": {
            "AddressLine": "1100-1198 N KENTUCKY ST",
            "PoliticalDivision2": "ARLINGTON",
            "PoliticalDivision1": "VA",
            "PostcodePrimaryLow": "22205",
            "PostcodeExtendedLow": "3516",
            "Region": "ARLINGTON VA 22205-3516",
            "CountryCode": "US"
        }
    }, {
        "AddressKeyFormat": {
            "AddressLine": "1101-1199 N KENTUCKY ST",
            "PoliticalDivision2": "ARLINGTON",
            "PoliticalDivision1": "VA",
            "PostcodePrimaryLow": "22205",
            "PostcodeExtendedLow": "3515",
            "Region": "ARLINGTON VA 22205-3515",
            "CountryCode": "US"
        }
    }, {
        "AddressKeyFormat": {
            "AddressLine": "1500-1598 N KENTUCKY ST",
            "PoliticalDivision2": "ARLINGTON",
            "PoliticalDivision1": "VA",
            "PostcodePrimaryLow": "22205",
            "PostcodeExtendedLow": "2825",
            "Region": "ARLINGTON VA 22205-2825",
            "CountryCode": "US"
        }
    }, {
        "AddressKeyFormat": {
            "AddressLine": "1501-1599 N KENTUCKY ST",
            "PoliticalDivision2": "ARLINGTON",
            "PoliticalDivision1": "VA",
            "PostcodePrimaryLow": "22205",
            "PostcodeExtendedLow": "2824",
            "Region": "ARLINGTON VA 22205-2824",
            "CountryCode": "US"
        }
    }, {
        "AddressKeyFormat": {
            "AddressLine": "1800-1899 N KENTUCKY ST",
            "PoliticalDivision2": "ARLINGTON",
            "PoliticalDivision1": "VA",
            "PostcodePrimaryLow": "22205",
            "PostcodeExtendedLow": "2826",
            "Region": "ARLINGTON VA 22205-2826",
            "CountryCode": "US"
        }
    }, {
        "AddressKeyFormat": {
            "AddressLine": "2000-2098 N KENTUCKY ST",
            "PoliticalDivision2": "ARLINGTON",
            "PoliticalDivision1": "VA",
            "PostcodePrimaryLow": "22205",
            "PostcodeExtendedLow": "3218",
            "Region": "ARLINGTON VA 22205-3218",
            "CountryCode": "US"
        }
    }, {
        "AddressKeyFormat": {
            "AddressLine": "2001-2099 N KENTUCKY ST",
            "PoliticalDivision2": "ARLINGTON",
            "PoliticalDivision1": "VA",
            "PostcodePrimaryLow": "22205",
            "PostcodeExtendedLow": "3217",
            "Region": "ARLINGTON VA 22205-3217",
            "CountryCode": "US"
        }
    }, {
        "AddressKeyFormat": {
            "AddressLine": "2100-2199 N KENTUCKY ST",
            "PoliticalDivision2": "ARLINGTON",
            "PoliticalDivision1": "VA",
            "PostcodePrimaryLow": "22205",
            "PostcodeExtendedLow": "3219",
            "Region": "ARLINGTON VA 22205-3219",
            "CountryCode": "US"
        }
    }
    ...
```

**What suggestions to make for the customer?**

Of course it makes sense to provide the first suggestion to the customer

*"Did you mean 2600 S KENT ST"?*

But how would you present the rest of the options where the `AddressLine` element contains a range of house numbers.

*1000-1098 N KENTUCKY ST*

### Question

Have you seen or implemented anything like this? - please provide a link where it can be found
Any hints is greatly appreciated

Comment: SmartyStreets used to have a jquery plugin that you can still demo here https://smartystreets.com/archive/jquery-plugin/website that shows an example of how to handle address suggestions. Disclaimer: I work at SmartyStreets

Comment: @camiblanch Thanks, is the service backed by UPS?

Comment: the US address data comes from USPS, not UPS, and the international data comes from a variety of other sources.

Comment: @Rasmus Can you please help to provide code for UPS. I have tried sample provide by UPS but its not return candidate result for any request only status coming as success.